# Slow Http Request handling in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

My foxx application gets data in parrallel (about 5-6 http connection). I also have a simple url which just have `console.log('I am called')` . I have 4 core and 16gb of memory. I am noticing that sometimes the following logs takes from 1 second to more than an hour to print

```
2016-03-12T17:02:53Z [11944] INFO /evm, incoming request from 127.0.0.1: GET http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/app/analysis/getStats
2016-03-12T17:02:53Z [11944] INFO I am called
```

I can see the cpu utilization is about 20% and memory utilization is about 50% only.

Can you suggest what could be the reason and where should I work on.

Comment: No. We are using Ubuntu AWS r3.xlarge Instances.

Comment: you're using the windows environment you were talking about [in that other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960846/how-to-avoid-arangodb-collection-locks/36043953#36043953) and using tracelog while you observe this? Ok, sorry for mixing this thread up ;)

Comment: Hi @deepak-agarwal, any more news on this? Did you work it out? or is there a way to reproduce this?

Comment: I moved one of the scheduled jobs to run only at midnight instead of every hour. I think that was locking the collection. I am not noticing this problem now. But, I still believe there is some locking issue. Because I really noticed the http request being delayed for more than 30 min sometimes and then getting timed out (and those http requests just process a simple message on console)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted then. In general I guess that sort of question is better suited as a github issue with a more detailed description how to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it with ArangoDB 2.8.5 like this using a sample foxx service:

```
controller.get('/', function (req, res) {
/*
  res.json(_.map(testRepo.all(), function (model) {
    return model.forClient();
  }));
*/
 console.log('I am called');

});
```

and tried to tease it with this tiny shell snippet:

```
for j in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0  ; do \
  for i in `seq 1 100` ; do \
     curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" \
      "http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/test/test"  &\
  done; \
  sleep 2; \
 done
```

but I see all loglines instantly appear in the arangodb logfile.
Can you edit your question how to reproduce this?